# Network based linked table locks for editing

Tags: ms-access

I have an issue with a table that locks over the network using ms-access. I split the database and have a front end with the user interface and the code and the back end with the linked tables. 
When I open the front end and want to add data to the table it is locked for entry (no row with the little *). In VB it gives me the "operation must use an updatable query" error when I want to add the data.
This was used to work perfectly but lately I had issues. If I close the front end and go to open directly the linked table on the network I can edit the table without problem. So I should have the rights to edit the files and they are not read only. 
Please advise.
Thank you

Comment: Just saw that now when I open the table directly on the network, the file opens also as read only.

Comment: Check effective network permissions on accdb file. It should have "Modify" permission.